# Online mp3 processing in java

Tags: java, tomcat, mp3

I am making kind of mp3 music store. What is solution to cut or mix 2 mp3 files on the tomcat web server?

cut - I mean to cut first 30 seconds and save it in different file.

mix - I mean to mix the song with some messages about "Trial Version" for example.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out the [jLayer mp3 library](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily in that the MP3 format can be effectively cut & pasted as a byte stream.  There are frames in any given MP3 stream and you could loose maybe 26ms of audio on either side but that's not audibly much; each frame length can be variable based on if it is a VBR vs. CBR MP3.

You should indeed check out some libraries (already mentioned).

A proper MP3 decoder/player should honor in-stream adjustment in bitrate even with CBR, alas most don't.  If you control the source audio data though, concatenating/trimming the MP3 data will concatenate/trim the audio.